# Why doesn't my ng-repeat work(angularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use angularjs(1.6). And I'm having a little trouble with ng-repeat. I have in my `constructor` an object array (with question, title...). And depending on today's date I get an object from the array using a variable. This object I want to display with ng-repeat, but I must have made a mistake I think. Nothing happens.

Here's an example of the object in the constructor:

```
 this.questions = [
    {
      date: '20/3',
      question: `How odl are you ?`,
      answer: { r1: '12', r2: '28', r3: '32' },
    },
    {
      date: '21/3',
      question: `What's your name? ?`,
      answer: { r1: 'Math', r2: 'Eric', r3: 'Ben' },
    },....
 ]
```

The variable that returns the object with the values I want to display according to the day:

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
const today = day + "/" + month;

this.newDates = this.questions.find(q => q.date === today)
```

I want to display what the `newDates` object contains.

And here is the html:

```
<h1 ng-repeat="newDate in ::$ctrl.newDates">{{ ::newDate.question }}</h1>
```

I must have made a stupid mistake or maybe I can't display the data of a dynamically created object...I can't find the solution if you can help me.

Comment: can you log `this.newDates` and check the value

Comment: I think you want `filter()` instead of `find()`

Comment: Yes, he gives me back the object I want. That is the first one in the array.

Comment: One question; why are you using a repeater when it appears you're only getting a single object out of your collection to display? If it's only one thing to display, you could just bind it directly.

Comment: @Chris right after, I will need a ng-repeat to display several on the same day... Otherwise yes, I can display it directly without going through ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
this.newDates = this.questions.filter(q => q.date === today)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. Yes it's true that for ng-repeat I must have a array

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which return an Array where as [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) object

```
this.newDates = this.questions.filter(q => q.date === today)
```

Note: If you are expect a single object keep your existing code and don't use `ngRepeat` just directly use

```
<h1>{{ ::$ctrl.newDates.question }}</h1>
```

Comment: Yes after I would have more object to post the same days, that's why I put ng-repeat. But it's true that in this case, I don't need it. Thank you for your answer

Comment: For your code to work with filter you have to put this in the html: `{{ ::$ctrl.newDates[0].question }}` .